# iMac mid 2010 running slow

Tags: macos, imac, startup, hdd

[Specs of the iMac, the iMac already have 8GB(Should be enough to handle Yosemite)]
[1]http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-i3-3.2-21-inch-aluminum-mid-2010-specs.html#macspecs1

Yesterday i bought this iMac, it's took around 45mins to boot up and it's unusable due to the slow response. Each click takes around 15mins to response. So i done a clean installation of yosemite and updated to the latest version. And it's now become normal(boot up around 3mins) except the temperature is high at around 110C. I open up the iMac and clean the dust inside(All three fan) but it's still running at around 100C.

But, when i try to copy VLC from the dmg, it's become slow again suddenly, though the boot up time didn't reach 45mins, but the OS become so laggy. I did not install any software except iStatMenus Trial and the VLC.

Any idea what is failing in this iMac?Could it be the HDD?
One more question, does putting on new thermal paste help cool down the iMac?

Comment: Did you look in the Activity monitor ?

Comment: yes, Cpu usage is close to 2-3%, HDD does not have significant reading/writing/, Ram is not utilize much. But the iMac just run super slow.

Comment: The only thing i can think of, is the HDD is failing soon. Another thing is the high temp, but the iMac run smooth with high temp for a few hours used. Any idea how to solve the high temp issues?

Comment: what app is highest in the activity monitor? as for the Temperature, it could be the heat sink needs new paste !

Comment: i did not run any apps, The iMac simply boot up slowly and once boot up remain slow. Can't really run activity monitor to check. Will let you know when i have the chance to do that. I was thinking to install the OS come with the mac, snow leopard.

Comment: OK, boot in Safe mode that should run faster then check the activity monitor.

Comment: Event start in safe mode it was still too slow, so i done another clean install. The installation took around 2 hours while the progress bar show 16mins. Can it be the hard drive is dying? But i dont hear any weird noise from the drive. I had new paste for the CPU and GPU but have not get a chance to check the temp yet.

Comment: Also, boot from Yosemite USB is fast, but booting a snow leopard from USB seems impossible (Too slow, have no progression in 1 hour and have no progress bar or any indicator).

Comment: Did you run the Apple Hardware Test ? also the HardDrive problems would be indicted in the Console log as I/O errors.

Comment: i wasn't able to run AHT, the console log can be seen while installation right?

Comment: i press and hold D key several time but it doesn't seems like running AHT, it's simply go straight to boot up. But holding D  does delay the apple logo showing up.

Comment: You probably do not have the AHT installed on your hard drive. The console log works as long you can operate the system (it is in your Utility folder).

Comment: i should make a bootable AHT, already downloaded the AHT for this model. But didn't do it yet.

Comment: In idle mode the system should not heat up at all and the fans should not be running. If it does heat up, then you have something running the CPU. That should show in the Activity monitor.

Comment: The CPU is 99.3% idle, i boot in verbose and it stuck at supported channels....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, i send it to some expert to check on it.
There is two reason the machine is slow:
1. KVR ram is used for the machine
2. The HDD is most probably faulty.

Swap this two things out it worked fine.